# Retrieving new data in the layer

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, kml

I am solving the way of writing data to KML file using OpenLayers in map application. I want to ask if OpenLayers can insert new coordinates into a layer after 2 seconds, for example. So far I have done it by loading KML every two seconds with all the data, which is very data intensive. As soon as I just added new ones, it wouldn't be as data intensive. Possible?